# Android - POST запрос на авторизацию

Tags: android, json, post, авторизация

Делаю авторизацию в своем приложении, столкнулся с проблемой что при вводе правильного логина и пароля авторизация не проходит, а просто переходит на следующий экран. Мне нужно после POST запроса, получить в ответ **токен** (для дальнейших манипулиций в приложении) или **ошибку** (неправильного ввода логина пароля) пример получения должен быть таким:

```
 {
   "success": true,
   "token": <token>
 }
```

Помогите с реализацией получения токена.
Вот моя реализация POST запроса авторизации:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Context c;
EditText ELogin;
EditText passwordText;
Button loginBtn;
String password;
String Login;
String url = "http://smktesting.herokuapp.com/api/login/";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login1);
    c = this;
    ELogin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_login);
    passwordText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_password);
    loginBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);

    loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //  _("Login button hit");

            Login = ELogin.getText() + "";
            password = passwordText.getText() + "";

            if ( Login.length() == 0 || password.length() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(c, "Please fill in all fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            if ( Login.length() > 0 && password.length() > 0) {
                //Do networking
                Networking n = new Networking();
                n.execute(url, Networking.NETWORK_STATE_lOGIN);
                Toast.makeText(c, "Login Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Spisok.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }

    });

}
public void onClickRegisters(View v){
    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
    startActivity(browserIntent);
}

//AsyncTask good for long running tasks
public class Networking extends AsyncTask {

    public static final int NETWORK_STATE_lOGIN = 1;

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {

        getJson((String) params[0], (Integer) params[1]);
        return null;
    }
}

private void getJson(String url, int state) {
    //Do a HTTP POST, more secure than GET
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
    List<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    boolean valid = false;

    switch (state) {
        case Networking.NETWORK_STATE_lOGIN:
            //Building key value pairs to be accessed on web
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", Login));
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

            valid = true;


            break;
        default:
            Toast.makeText(c, "Unknown state", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    if (valid == true) {
        //Reads everything that comes from server
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
        try {
            UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters);
            request.setEntity(entity);

            //Send off to server
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

            //Reads response and gets content
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

            String line = "";
            String LineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            //Read back server output
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuffer.append(line + LineSeparator);
            }

            bufferedReader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        decodeResultIntoJson(stringBuffer.toString());
    } else {
  }
}

private void decodeResultIntoJson(String response) {
    if (response.contains("error")) {
        try {
            JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(response);
            String error = jo.getString("error");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    try {
        JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(response);
        String success = jo.getString("success");
        String message = jo.getString("message");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сейчас у тебя выполняется запрос и независимо от его результатов открывается новое активити. Тебе же нужно производить запуск активити, только если результат запроса success = true и в ответ пришел token:

```
private void decodeResultIntoJson(String response) {
    Boolean success;
    if (response.contains("success")) {
        try {
            JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(response);
            success= jo.getBoolean("success");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(succes){
            try {
            JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(response);
            String token= jo.getString("token");
            //здесь записываешь token куда-либо или просто передаешь через интент    в другое активити
            Toast.makeText(c, "Login Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Spisok.class);
            intent.putExtra("token", token);
            startActivity(intent);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else{
            //сообщаешь об ошибке удобным способом (алерт, тост или как пожелаешь)   
            try {
                JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(response);
                String message = jo.getString("message ");
                Toast.makeText(this, message , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вроде работает, единственные "но" приложение крашится если не закоментить строки:
      Toast.makeText(c, "Login Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      Toast.makeText(this, message , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
И можно ли проверить как то записано ли значение в переменную token? просто есть подозрение что оно передает пустой токен в следующие активити.

Comment: Ну потому что в метод makeText первым параметром нужно передавать контекст, поэтому нужно заменить первые параметры на LoginActivity.this. Проверить легко - во втором активити:     String token = getIntent().getExtras().getString("token"). и переменную токен либо выведи в лог, либо на экран либо тем же Toast. ну либо в редиме отладки пошагово смотри переменные.

Comment: Заменил как вы сказали получились строчки:  
Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Но приложение все также при вводе правильного или неправильного логина пароля крашится.
На счет токена его проверил он все таки пустой, значит проблема уже не у меня а у сервера?

Comment: на счет краша я не могу ничего сказать, я же не вижу лога)) а на счет токена - либи запрос на сервер не правильный либо еще что-то. Можешь скинуть проект на почту (bznikita95@yandex.ru)  - я посмотрю.

Comment: Отправил проверьте почту.

Comment: да, получил, сейчас посмотрю.